# How to convert each to a foreach statement, so that my code runs in PHP 8?

Tags: php

This is the old code that is now null and void due to the each function no longer working in PHP version 8:

```
case pdf_parser::TYPE_DICTIONARY:

            // A dictionary.
            $this->_straightOut('<<');

            reset ($value[1]);

            while (list($k, $v) = each($value[1])) {
                $this->_straightOut($k . ' ');
                $this->_writeValue($v);
            }

            $this->_straightOut('>>');
            break;
```

I need to convert the each statement to "foreach" and I tried the following:

```
foreach ($k as $v => $value[1]) {
```

How can I rewrite my code above so it works with the foreach statement?

Comment: If you can, please try to avoid asking for free work. Questions here get a much better reception if the author shows that they know the work is theirs to do. This is as much about developing an independence mindset as it is not giving excessive work requests to volunteers. In any case, you will probably find that readers _will_ do the work for you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just transform the deprecated each to

```
foreach($value[1] as $k => $v) {
    $this->_straightOut($k . ' ');
    $this->_writeValue($v);
}
```

Comment: To note; please edit and confirm the `while` aspect should also be removed